# How to do Character Encoding in a WebView?

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, webview

I have an app in which there are several WebViews, each displaying a paragraph of description text. Almost all of them have garbled characters in them, usually where there are single quotes or double quotes.

For example, a string which should look like the following:

> Body ‘N’ Space

Ends up looking like this in the WebView:

> Body ÂNÂ Space

Here's what I first tried:

```
textWebView.loadData(getHtmlDescription(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I ended up trying many solutions, including the following:

Adding this before `loadData`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = textWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
```

Changing `loadData` to `loadDataWithBaseURL`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = textWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
textWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlDescription(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Changing `"text/html"` to `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = textWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
textWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlDescription(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

And unfortunately, none of those solutions did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all those solutions without success, I ended up trying to just find and replace all the bad characters I could see. That was just too cumbersome and inefficient, but somehow I stumbled on the following two-line fix that did the job for all of it!

In my `getHtmlDescription()` method, I added these two lines:

```
description = description.replace("Â", "");
description = Html.fromHtml(description, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
return description;
```

Comment: Note for those supporting API's earlier than 24: `Html.fromHtml(description).toString();` will do the job as well.